# ERROR (make: *** No rule to make target `check'. Stop.)

Tags: makefile, terminal, make-install

I want to download an API called libtrading, the process to download it in terminal is as the follows,

OSX

```
$ brew install libevent glib pkgconfig
$ pip install pyyaml
```

Then run:

```
$ make install
```

You can also run the test harness:

```
$ make check
```

I have successfully processed the first two steps, but when I put 'make install' and 'make check', it always says (make: *** No rule to make target `check'.  Stop. )

Does anyone know how can I solve the problem? Is it because some file path is needed here? but I don't know what is it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you failed to download `libtrading` itself, or forgot to extract its files, or extracted its files in a different location. `make` needs a `Makefile` as input in order to do anything at all.

Comment: The instructions actually say nothing about how to download the package. Presumably, if you are about to start compiling C code, you are supposed to understand implicitly how to download the code (`git clone` the repo, I guess).

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I forgot to clone it, thank you so much!